# Regex: Doesn't works in some cases

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I am really new to `regex` and was practicing it. First check out this code:

```
$(".app").each(function(){
    var raw_string = $(this).html();
    var changed_string = raw_string.replace(/^\{\{|\}\}$/g, "");
    $(this).html(eval(changed_string));
});
```

I am trying to look into the HTML of `.app` and searching for anything that starts with mustache `{{` and ends with mustache `}}`. Just like `Mustache.js`. First I am replacing it with an empty string and then setting the HTML of `.app` to `eval(changed_string)`. So if I try:

```
<div class="app">

    {{2+2}}

</div>
```

Working absolutely fine printing 4. But:

## THE PROBLEM

If I add some additional HTML to `.app`:

```
<div class="app">

    2 and 2 are: {{2+2}}

</div>
```

The output is:

```
2 and 2 are: {{2+2}}
```

### What is happening???

[JsFiddle Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/bbzh4Lp6/4/)

Comment: you can achieve it using group capturing if you want http://jsfiddle.net/LbpxLb4b/

Comment: @YuliamChandra I just want to evaluate this `{{ any_code }}` to javascript. Not to replace all the other HTML with `{{ any_code }}` !!!

Comment: @YuliamChandra what is this anonymous function doing here??

Comment: callback of each matching group capturing, first param is the whole string, second param is the matching (.*)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fixing the expression (you're matching the beginning/end of the string) still won't solve the problem; you'll try to evaluate the whole string, including "2 and 2 are:...".

Try this, replacing the stuff inside each `{{...}}` pair:

```
$(".app").each(function(){
    var raw_string = $(this).html();
    var changed_string = raw_string.replace(/\{\{(.+)\}\}/g, 
      function( match, p1 ) {
        return(eval(p1));
      }                                     
    );
    $(this).html(changed_string);
});
```

Comment: Thanks! One question: what if there are many `(.*)` in the expression. What would be the value of the second param??

Comment: The second param would hold the value of the *first* group. You'd add more parameters (`p2`, `p3`, or whatever you prefer) to catch the values of the other groups.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your .replace(...) isn't capturing what's between the mustaches, it's just removing the mustaches. So in the second case, you're then trying to eval a string instead of a valid expression, i.e. `eval("2 and 2 are: 2+2");`

The fix is to .exec or .match with capturing group `()`, and extract the captured string for eval.

```
    $(".app").each(function(){
        var raw_string = $(this).html();
        var reg = new RegExp(/\{\{(.*)\}\}/);
        var formula = reg.exec(raw_string); // captures orig string in formula[0], first match in formula[1]
        $(this).html(eval(formula[1]));
    });
```